# Static vertex arrays?

Tags: opengl, static

Is it necessary for vertex (or color, etc) arrays in OpenGL to be static? From the [OpenGL red book chapter 2](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html):

```
static GLint vertices[] = {25, 25,
                      100, 325,
                      175, 25,
                      175, 325,
                      250, 25,
                      325, 325};
static GLfloat colors[] = {1.0, 0.2, 0.2,
                      0.2, 0.2, 1.0,
                      0.8, 1.0, 0.2,
                      0.75, 0.75, 0.75,
                      0.35, 0.35, 0.35,
                      0.5, 0.5, 0.5};

 glEnableClientState (GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

 glColorPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
 glVertexPointer (2, GL_INT, 0, vertices);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't have to be static, in the sense you can dynamically allocate them. Though, they must not be freed until you're done rendering, that is, after the call to `glDrawArrays`. An alternative is to use Vertex Buffer Objects which allow you to upload that memory to the GPU.

Comment: Then is there any reason to even have them as static?

Answer (score 0):

this chunks of memory (for the vertex data and for the colors) must be available when you call a drawing function - like DrawArrays, DrawElements, etc...

glVertexPointer only sets a pointer... but does not copy any data to the opengl

you can declare those arrays inside a Render function for instance... or have them declared globally.